# JQuery removing class with pointer-events none not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a class:

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and I remove it using jquery:

```
$('#button').removeClass('disabled')
```

and class gets disabled, but clicking on this link still does not work - clicking on it does not redirect to href link (actually, nothing happens).

On the other hand, if I use attr disabled on link and then remove it using

```
$('#button').prop('disabled', false)
```

It does work...

But on my project devs are using 'disabled' class for disabling links (not sure why), so I want to stick with it, any suggestions?

PS. After removing class 'disabled' checking `$('#button').css('pointer-events')` returns `auto`, so It should work, I am lost.

My example:

```
<a id='my-button' href="www.google.com" class='disabled' style="display: block;"><i class="pti pt-trophy"></i><span>Click me</span></a>
```

css:

```
a.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and after clicking on some other div I change this links href and remove class:

```
$("#my-button").attr('href', result['success']['new_link']);
$("#my-button").removeClass('disabled');
```

(result is an object conating ajax results and new link, checked multiple times, It is defined and correct, console throws no errors, so does server)

Comment: Please define "_does not work_", and where is our [mcve]?

Comment: little demo https://jsfiddle.net/wjjgwvcm/

Comment: Your demo works as expected, it removes the class with pointer-events rule, and the "Send" button is clickable again.

Comment: yes @David, your demo works perfectly and it will work in all cases the why is **Jakub**'s code is not working. **Jakub** please share your code.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice it wasn't OP's fiddle ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing something in your code, I made a working example for you:

```js
$("button:first").click(function(){
    $("button:last").toggleClass("disabled")
    $("button:last").text(function(i, text){
          return text === "Disabled" ? "Click me" : "Disabled";
      })
});
$("button:last").click(function(){
    console.log("clicked")
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Toggle Disable for bottom button</button><br><br>
<button type="button" class="disabled">Disabled</button>
```